# Why my process is still running after I log out?

Tags: bash

After logging in through `ssh`, I type this command in `bash`:

```
sleep 50000000000000 &
```

Then I `kill -9` the `sleep` process’s parent process (i.e., `bash`). Then the terminal window disconnects simultaneously.

When I log in again, I find that the `sleep` process is still alive.

**Question**: Why can the `sleep` process survive when I log out and the terminal is closed? In my mind, everything except daemons and `nohup` programs will be killed during logout. If `sleep` can survive in this way, does it mean that I can use this method instead of the `nohup` command?

Comment: `&` will fork the process to background (like daemon) and keeps running eventhough you are logged out.

Answer (score 7):

#### Tl;dr:

> Why can the `sleep` process survive when I log out and the terminal is closed? In my mind, everything except daemons and `nohup` programs will be killed during logout. If `sleep` can survive in this way, does it mean that I can use this method instead of the `nohup` command?

Unless the `bash` instance spawned by `ssh` has the `huponexit` option set, no process will be terminated by any mean upon exit / log out, and when the `huponexit` option is set, using `kill -9` on the shell is not a good alternative to using `nohup` on the shell's child processes; `nohup` on the shell's child processes will still protect them from SIGHUPs not coming from the shell, and even when that is not important `nohup` is still to be preferred because it allows the shell to be terminated gracefully.

---

In `bash` there's an option called `huponexit`, which if set will make `bash` SIGHUP its children upon exit / logout;

In interactive *non-login* `bash` instances, such as in a `bash` instance spawned by `gnome-terminal`, this option is ignored; whether `huponexit` is set or unset, `bash`'s children will never be SIGHUPped by `bash` upon exit;

In interactive *login* `bash` instances, such as in a `bash` instance spawned by `ssh`, this option is not ignored (however it is unset by default); if `huponexit` is set, `bash`'s children will be SIGHUPped by `bash` upon exit / logout; if `huponexit` is unset, `bash`'s children will not be SIGHUPped by `bash` upon exit / logout;

So in general exiting / logging out from an interactive login `bash` instance, unless the `huponexit` option is set, won't make the shell SIGHUP its children, and exiting / logging out from an interactive non-login `bash` instance won't make the shell SIGHUP its children regardless;

This is, however, irrelevant in this case: using `kill -9` `sleep` will survive regardless, because killing its parent process (`bash`) won't leave a chance for the latter to do *anything* to the former (i.e., e.g., if the current `bash` instance was a login `bash` instance and the `huponexit` option was set, to SIGHUP it).

Adding to this, unlike other signals (like a SIGHUP signal sent to `bash`), a SIGKILL signal is never propagated to a process's child processes, hence `sleep` is not even killed;

`nohup` starts a process immune to SIGHUP signals, which is something different; it will prevent the process hanging up upon the reception of a SIGHUP signal, which in this case could be received by the interactive login `bash` instance in case the `huponexit` option was set and the shell exited; so technically using `nohup` to start a process in an interactive login `bash` instance with the `huponexit` option unset will prevent the process from hanging up upon the reception of a SIGHUP signal, but exiting / logging out of the shell won't SIGHUP it regardless;

In general, however, when `nohup` is needed to prevent SIGHUP signals coming from the parent shell, there's no reason to prefer the `kill -9` on the parent method to the `nohup` on the child method; instead, it should be the opposite.

Killing the parent using the `kill -9` method doesn't leave a chance for the parent to exit gracefully, while starting the child using the `nohup` method allows the parent to be terminated by other signals, such as SIGHUP (to make an example which makes sense in the context of a child started using `nohup`), which allow it to exit gracefully.

Comment: In other words, if I have a script that was placed in background,it will still be running even if I kill the parent process, e.g. my shell right ? what would be a way to kill that script ?

Comment: @Serg If you have the PID, simply killing the PID; if you didn't store the PID but you can identify the process by his name, `ps -e | grep process` should list the proces along with the PID (or better just `pgrep -x process` if you are sure to match that single process and not unwnated things); the problem is that when you kill a process with `kill -9` its children get owned by `upstart`, hence their original PPID is lost and their PPID changes to upstart's PID, making them unrecognizable (AFAIK) but for their name or PID

Comment: @kos Under what condition `nohup` will fail to prevent a process from hanging up upon receiving a SIGHUP signal from the parent process? I am trying to run a process in the background (in a PuTTY SSH shell terminal) by `nohup <command> <arg> &`. When I logout by clicking the PuTTY `X` button, the background process will terminate immediately. When I logout by typing `exit` in the PuTTY SSH shell terminal, the process will continue to run in the background.

Answer (score 3):

`bash` by default [does not send down the HUP signal to child processes when exiting](https://serverfault.com/questions/117152/do-background-processes-get-a-sighup-when-logging-off). More in detail (thanks @kos), it never does it for [non-login shells](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155865/what-are-login-and-non-login-shells).

You can configure bash to do it for [login shells](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155865/what-are-login-and-non-login-shells) if set the option `huponexit`. In a terminal, do:

```
[romano:~] % bash -l
```

(this start a new "login" shell)

```
romano@pern:~$ shopt -s huponexit
romano@pern:~$ sleep 1234 &
[1] 32202
romano@pern:~$ exit
logout
```

Now check for the `sleep` process:

```
[romano:~] % ps augx | grep sleep
romano   32231  0.0  0.0  16000  2408 pts/11   S+   15:23   0:00 grep sleep
```

...not running: it has received the HUP signal and exited as requested.

Comment: @kos --- yes, you are right but ... so why if I `sleep 1000 & ; exit` the `sleep` survives? Notice that if I `kill -HUP` the `sleep` process it *will* exit. And even if `huponexit` set, the `sleep` survives. Confused... (I will try to understand better and modify the asnwer, otherwise I'll delete it).

Answer (score 2):

> If `sleep` can survive in this way, if it means that I can use this
>   method instead of `nohup` command?

`kill -9` is really not the way one should go. It's like shooting with a gun at the TV to turn it off. Besides the comedic component there is no advantage. Processes can't catch or ignore `SIGKILL`. If you don't give the process a chance to finish what it's doing and clean up, it may leave corrupted files (or other state) around and won't be able to start again. `kill -9` is the last hope, when nothing else works.

---

> Why sleep process can survive when I logout and terminal is closed. In
>   my mind, everything except daemon and nohup program will be killed
>   when logout.

What in your case happens:

The parent process of `sleep` is the currently running `bash` shell. When you `kill -9` that bash, the bash process has not the chance to send a `SIGHUP` to any of its child processes, because `SIGKILL` (which is sent by `kill -9`) is not catchable by the process. The sleep process continues running. sleep now became an [orphan process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process).

The init (PID 1) process does a mechanism called reparenting. That means that the init process now becomes the parent of that orphaned process. init is an exception, processes can become it's child as it collects processes that lost their original parent process. Btw: A daemon (like `sshd`) does that when "going in the background".

If that whould not happen, the orphaned process would later (when finished) become a zombie process. This is what happens when `waitpid()` is not called (a responsibility of the parent process which cannot be fullfilled when when that process got killed). init calls `waitpid()` in an specific intervall to avoid zombie childs.

Comment: The process is surviving even with polite signals like `TERM` or `HUP`

Comment: @heemayl HUP depends on the shells config: `huponext`. And TERM will wait until sleep finished. In case of the OPs sleep command, it would be thousands of years =)

Answer (score 1):

The `&` starts the process in background. If you type `ps -ef`, you will see that parent process ID (PPID) of your sleep is your bash. Then logout and login again. The process will remain running after you logout. After you login for the second time you run `ps -ef` again. You will see that now the parent of your sleep process will be process with id "1". That is init, the parent of all processes.

Answer (score 0):

Using `&` will cause program to run as background. To see the program in the background use `bg` command , and to make it running as foreground again, run `fg`.

Yes, there are many ways to keep program running even the main terminal exited.

Comment: thanks.  the man page of bash is a little confusing. It said that : "Before exiting, an interactive shell resends the SIGHUP to all jobs,  running       or stopped. " BUT in fact, the shell only send SIGHUP to the **forground** jobs. the background processes have no chance to receive the SIGHUP signal (unless change the 'huponexit' shell options)

Comment: @kos maybe you are right. I draw the above conclusion from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298741/how-bash-handles-the-jobs-when-logout    now, I get myself more confused.

Comment: @tom_cat Back to this again, thinking about it twice: there's simply no case in which the shell can *exit* with a foreground process running, it can be SIGHUPped or something, but that's not *exiting*. So that's correct, it applies only to background processes, because the opposite would make no sense. However from further research, mind also that `huponexit` works only on login shells such as a shell obtained via `ssh` (and not, say, in a shell obtained via `gnome-terminal`)

Answer (score 0):

There's two kinds of `SIGHUP` that can be involved here.

First, because in this kind of situation, the shell will be a so called *Controlling Process* (a session leader shell in ownership of a controlling terminal--a pseudoterminal created by the ssh login), a terminal driver will be obligated to send `SIGHUP` to all members of the foreground process group of the terminal when the terminal is disconnected.

(It will also send `SIGHUP`+`SIGCONT` to stopped backgrounded processes (orphan process groups)).

You've ruled such a system-sent `SIGHUP` out by **backgrounding** the process while being in an **interactive shell**. Such backgrounding will put the process(es) in a separate process group that won't be the foreground process group of the terminal, and so the driver won't send `SIGHUP` to such processes.

Backgrounding by itself isn't the issue, but you need to background from a shell that's noninteractive (interactive shells put backgrounded processes in separate process groups) and part of the foreground process group:

```
#from a ssh login shell
bash -c 'echo $$; sleep 1000 & sleep 1000 && wait' 
#a backgrounded and a nonbackgrounded sleep, both in the foreground process group
```

Now if you were to `kill -9` the echoed shell pid from another terminal, both the sleep processes would receive `SIGHUP` from the terminal driver (a `sigaction`-registered signal handler would read the sender's pid as `si_pid==0`).

Second there's `SIGHUP`s sent by the shell depending on its settings (`si_pid!=0`). An interactive bash resends received `SIGHUP`s to all its foreground jobs.
This behavior allows you to have several interactive bashes on top of each other (like if you were to run `bash` from the login bash and possibly some bash instances (no `&` at the end) from it)
and rest assured a `SIGHUP` from the first (controlling) bash gets sent down even though each controlling bash will create its own process group and so the `SIGHUP` sent by the terminal driver wouldn't be able to reach the descendants.  (Not all shell have this. E.g., Dash doesn't.) Bash will also resend `SIGHUP` to its backgrounded processes, but only if the `huponexit` setting is on and the job isn't `disown`ed. None of these resends can apply if the shell was forcibly killed by `SIGKILL` (`kill -9`).

*Edit:*

Just found a very relevant answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32786211/1084774 by [gavv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3169754/gavv) which has a couple more details.