# How child process still running when i exit terminal window?

Tags: process, dd

When I execute

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null
```

Then close terminal window i see that `dd` still running  and it's PPID is difference than first time.
What is happening for `dd` process ?

whenever killing parent process kill the child process?

Answer (score 3):

Closing an interactive non-login terminal (such as a terminal window in Gnome or kde) won't send a SIGHUP signal. You can change that behavior in other type of shell (via a huponexit option) but not in interactive non-login term's.
See https://askubuntu.com/a/685291/798765 for more details on huponexit ;)

Comment: As for the PPID, does it become the same as upstart's PID (on mobile right now, cant try myself) ? See Kos' comment on the answer above

Comment: I think the process is _re-parented_ to the init (pid 1) process in this case. Nowadays that's systemd.

Comment: But it's parent is killed! How does the child is allive?

Comment: @Sinoosh: Child processes aren't killed upon their parents' death by default.

Comment: @Sinoosh See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21869303 and man kill ("negatives PID values may be used to choose whole process groups(...)")