# What is the meaning of -bash?

Tags: bash

I typed the command `echo $0` in tty1, and it returned `-bash`, why not `bash`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It indicates that `bash` was started as a login shell. From [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html), section `INVOCATION` (emphasis mine):

```
A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a -,  or
one started with the --login option.
...
When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a  non-inter‐
active  shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes com‐
mands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.   After  reading
that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,
in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one  that
exists  and  is  readable.  The --noprofile option may be used when the
shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

When a login shell exits, bash reads and  executes  commands  from   the
file ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.
```

`$0`, of course, is argument zero.

In Ubuntu, typically `.profile` exists and `.bash_profile` and `.bash_login` don't. So, a login shell reads `.profile`.

---

See also:

- [What are login and non-login shells?](https://askubuntu.com/q/155865/158442)
- [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38175/70524)