# Login for Terminal

Tags: command-line, login, gnome-terminal

When I run terminal in Linux Ubuntu, it runs normally. By that I mean that there is no login required. I am actually not sure if it is supposed to ask for login information, but I am wondering if there is a way that I could make the terminal ask for such whenever I run it.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to do this though?

Comment: When you log in to your session you are already logged in.

Comment: @edwinksl I just wanted to do it for fun!

Comment: @userDepth, so I can't, right?

Comment: @BrailinsonA.Disla If you want to log in into a terminal you can hit CTRL ALT F1 and you'll get one and F2 has another but remember you'll need CTRL ALT F7 to return to your graphical session. And no you won't be able to play music at the same time :P

Comment: @userDepth thanks a lot! 
I am barely starting to learn Linux and I actually did that before (CTRL ALT F1) and ended up turning off my computer because I did not know how to go back :P

Comment: Why would you want that? It would provide this kind of protection: http://www.funnyjunk.com/funny_pictures/1130278/Toll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any task that require a root previledges, you will be asked for root (`sudo`) password.

As userDepth said in comment that *When you log in to your session you are already logged in*,

> Login for terminal, What is it? What happened when we open it?

It is a **non-login interactive shell**. In this case of an **interactive** but **non-login** shell, only `~/.bashrc` is executed. In most cases, the default ~/.bashrc script executes the system’s `/etc/bashrc`.

You can read:

- [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/46856#46856)
- [What are login and non-login shells?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155865/what-are-login-and-non-login-shells?rq=1)
- [Differentiate Interactive login and non-interactive non-login shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879364/interactive-login-and-non-interactive-non-login-shell#879400)

---

When you  login to system and open a terminal,it's a gnome-terminal and when you did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, it is Virtual terminal. Virtual terminals can be accessed  by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> till <kbd>F6</kbd>. To come back to the graphical session, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you @daisy! Understanding the differences between login-shell and non-login shell would had been very helpful before I even asked the question, so thank you a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

On my side, it's revesed. Ctrl + Alt + F1 turns me back to graphical session. Ctrl + Alt + F3 takes me to the terminal session.